# What is the purpose of sensors and pumps with less than 1 ATM pressure?

Tags: pressure, atmospheric-science

This question is not directly a physics questions, though related a little.

Previously for sensors, and currently for air pumps, I am doing some research.

I have found a digital pressure sensor on Farnell that has "maximum" 0.10 bar measurement. (I cannot find the link right now).

Another is an air pump. http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/JQT-3000-C-electric-high-capacity_1677414765.html?s=p

(This is not an advertisement in any way.)

This product says its maximum pressure is 35 kpa that is 0.35 bar.

According to Google 1 atm = 1.01325 bar.

If the maximum pressure of these devices are less than the pressure of atmosphere, then what is the purpose of them? How can a pump with less than 1 ATM pressure can do any compression? Or where am I going to be using a 0.1 bar sensor? In a vacuum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct.  They're for vacuum use.  There are pumps and sensors that go to much higher vacuums as well.  One torr is equal to .001 bar.  It's quite common to find vacuum systems with pressures lower than $1\times10^{-6}$ torr.

Example of vacuum hose:
[image: The thick red rubber hose is the vacuum hose]

Comment: So, I guess the pressure in a thick pipe can drop below 1 ATM without losing its shape, and that pump blows that. I cannot imagine any other type of vacuum environment. People are not using these in Space Station, right?

Comment: I would say the pump sucks more than blows.  Yes on the thick pipe, or hose, see picture above.  I don't know for a fact that they use them on the space station, but it wouldn't much of a surprise.  Vacuum pumps are pretty common tools for lots of scientific experiments.